# Approach with Spring Boot app for update

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot

I have two Spring Boot 2.0 applications as a services: the first one is main app  with postgres database and the second is app which should do full update for first app(stop main app, backup/update postgres DB, replace jar file, run main app, etc). Also I want to use docker for this(first app in container, postgres in container and second app in container). May by anybody had the same situation how to manage docker container from other docker container or this is bad approach and I should use second app without docker container to manage those? Or may be it helps to use orchestration(kubernates) for this?

Now I don't use docker and execute bash scripts from second app to do update for first app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a second app you should take a look at docker-compose and schedule some shell scripts.
Docker-compose is able to build dependencies between different docker images and has also commands to rebuild the docker images and start the images up again.
I think together with some shell scripts and docker-compose you can achieve your goal.

Without any programming skill and without second application.

On the other hand if you setup all with docker-compose and shell scripts you can also execute this command from another Spring Boot app as you like.

Start your journey here https://docs.docker.com/compose/ there are also good tutorials on youtube.